# Unable to resolve '_WorkbookChild" has no attribute "max_row" [attr-defined]' warning with openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl, mypy

With the python file below I am unable to resolve mypy errors.

```
import openpyxl

inputWorkbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("input.xlsx")
activeSheet = inputWorkbook.active
if activeSheet:
    print(activeSheet.max_row)
```

I keep getting this error `test.py:6: error: "_WorkbookChild" has no attribute "max_row"  [attr-defined]`. Looking at the documentation I dont see what the issue is. [openpyxl.workbook.workbook().active](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.active) returns type [openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet) which include [max_row](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.max_row).

- Python            3.11.3
- mypy              1.3.0
- mypy-extensions   1.0.0
- openpyxl          3.1.2

Comment: Probably worth checking exactly what the sheet is: it could be a ChartSheet, for example.

Answer (score 0):

`openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.active` property is typed to return `openpyxl.workbook.child._WorkbookChild` and `max_row attribute` is not present in `_WorkbookChild`, it is due to static type checking.

Add a `type: ignore` comment and it should solve the warning.

```
import openpyxl

inputWorkbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("input.xlsx")
activeSheet = inputWorkbook.active
if activeSheet:
    print(activeSheet.max_row)  # type: ignore
```

Comment: Where do you see that in the source code? Looking at https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.1/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py#L63 and https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/branch/3.1/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py#L153 openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.active doesnt have typing

Comment: Wrong solution indeed, I am not sure how to solve your problem in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the [built-in typings](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stubs/openpyxl/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.pyi), which differ slightly from the actual implementation (not quite sure why, if anyone else can shed light). Some options are:

- Use [different type stubs](https://github.com/MartinThoma/openpyxl-stubs/blob/main/openpyxl-stubs/workbook/workbook.pyi#L72)
- Use `cast` from the `typing` module:

```py
    import openpyxl
    from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet
    from typing import cast
    
    inputWorkbook = openpyxl.load_workbook("input.xlsx")
    activeSheet = cast( Worksheet, inputWorkbook.active )
    if activeSheet:
        print(activeSheet.max_row)
```